# Compiling Tesseract native library for Android (libtess.so) on a Windows PC

Tags: docker, tesseract

I am trying to compile Tesseract 4.x for Android, and get the libtess.so/libtesseract.so file (32bit & 64 bit) which is compatible with a LSTM traineddata file.
Now, here is the link for official docs for this :

- [Tesseract_compilation_guide_Android](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html#android)
- [Tesseract_compilation_with_docker](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/4.0-Docker-Containers)

I tried both the docker approach and the terminal approach (on a Windows machine with Cgywin). But got stuck in both cases.

For docker approach, the error was :

pull access denied for bad-tiff, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

for the line 
"FROM bad-tiff:4.0.10-$ARCH AS tiff-dep" in [dockerfile_link_badTesseract_GitRepo](https://github.com/rhardih/bad/blob/master/tesseract/tesseract-4.0.0.Dockerfile)

For terminal approach, using cgywin, couldn't run 
"ndk-build -C tess-two-git/tess-two tesseract APP_ABI=arm64-v8a"
from [tesseract_doc_link](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html#android), with error "NDK command not found" error.

Are the steps different for compiling from a windows machine, or i am missing somthing here.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691997/how-to-use-tesseract-4-on-a-android-platform-armv7-arm64/61802887#61802887) thread to compile tesseract 4 on windows