# How to use (compile) Tesseract 4 on a Android platform (armv7 & arm64)

Tags: android, tesseract

Currently I am using Tesseract 3 in an android application (armv7 & arm64 architectures). But, I need to upgrade to Tesseract 4 for using some of its additional features.
How do I upgrade to Tesseract 4?

These are the things I tried so far:

1. [compiling_on_terminal_or_androidStudio](https://github.com/alexcohn/tess-two/blob/4.1/BUILDING.md)
2. [compiling_using_docker](https://github.com/rhardih/bad)

Issues with those approaches:

1. [issue_with_terminal_approach](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/1fOt6uVLB0Q)
2. [issue_with_docker_approach](https://github.com/rhardih/bad/issues/13)

Error log :

```
D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess>gradlew assemble

> Task :eyes-two:generateJsonModelDebug FAILED
make: *** No rule to make target 'D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build//intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/liblept.so', needed by 'D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhydrogen.so'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build//intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/liblept.so', needed by 'D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/arm64-v8a/libhydrogen.so'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build//intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/liblept.so', needed by 'D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86/libhydrogen.so'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build//intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86_64/liblept.so', needed by 'D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86_64/libhydrogen.so'.  Stop.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':eyes-two:generateJsonModelDebug'.
> Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib TESSERACT_BUILD_PATH=D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
  md "D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib\armeabi-v7a" >NUL 2>NUL || rem
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Gdbserver      ": "[arm-linux-androideabi] D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver"
  copy /b/y "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\\..\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver\gdbserver" "D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib\armeabi-v7a\gdbserver" > NUL
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Gdbsetup       ": "D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe "set solib-search-path D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a" > D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe "directory C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/common C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/android/cpufeatures D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/imageutils/../common D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/opticalflow/../common" >> D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
  md "D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs\hydrogen\src" >NUL 2>NUL || rem
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "hydrogen <= clusterer.cpp"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/clusterer.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpic -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Oz -DNDEBUG  -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen    -DANDROID  -Wno-error=format-security   -c  D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src/clusterer.cpp -o D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/clusterer.o
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "hydrogen <= hydrogentextdetector.cpp"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/hydrogentextdetector.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpic -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Oz -DNDEBUG  -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen    -DANDROID  -Wno-error=format-security   -c  D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src/hydrogentextdetector.cpp -o D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/hydrogentextdetector.o
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "hydrogen <= thresholder.cpp"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/thresholder.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpic -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Oz -DNDEBUG  -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen    -DANDROID  -Wno-error=format-security   -c  D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src/thresholder.cpp -o D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/thresholder.o
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "hydrogen <= utilities.cpp"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/utilities.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpic -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Oz -DNDEBUG  -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen    -DANDROID  -Wno-error=format-security   -c  D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src/utilities.cpp -o D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/utilities.o
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "hydrogen <= validator.cpp"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/validator.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpic -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Oz -DNDEBUG  -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen    -DANDROID  -Wno-error=format-security   -c  D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src/validator.cpp -o D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/src/validator.o
  md "D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs\hydrogen\jni" >NUL 2>NUL || rem
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "hydrogen <= hydrogentextdetector.cpp"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/jni/hydrogentextdetector.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpic -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Oz -DNDEBUG  -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen    -DANDROID  -Wno-error=format-security   -c  D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/jni/hydrogentextdetector.cpp -o D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/jni/hydrogentextdetector.o
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "hydrogen <= thresholder.cpp"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/jni/thresholder.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpic -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Oz -DNDEBUG  -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen    -DANDROID  -Wno-error=format-security   -c  D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/jni/thresholder.cpp -o D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/jni/thresholder.o
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/echo.exe [armeabi-v7a] "Compile++ thumb": "hydrogen <= jni.cpp"
  C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe -MMD -MP -MF D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/jni/jni.o.d -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi16 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes  --sysroot C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -Wno-invalid-command-line-argument -Wno-unused-command-line-argument  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fpic -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Oz -DNDEBUG  -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/src -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android -ID:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build/../../leptonica/src -ID:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen    -DANDROID  -Wno-error=format-security   -c  D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/src/main/jni/hydrogen/jni/jni.cpp -o D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/hydrogen/jni/jni.o
  md "D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\eyes-two\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local\armeabi-v7a" >NUL 2>NUL || rem

  make: *** No rule to make target 'D:\Kunal\tess_related\tess-backup\tess\tess-two\build//intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/liblept.so', needed by 'D:/Kunal/tess_related/tess-backup/tess/eyes-two/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libhydrogen.so'.  Stop.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't bother with official docs, they won't be of any help.

Main resource to follow : [Tesseract_4_with_Android](https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android)

Using Android Studio, follow the steps (as instructed [here](https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android#android-studio)) :

- Open this project in Android Studio
- Open Gradle panel, expand `Tesseract4Android / :tesseract4Android / Tasks / other` and run `assembleRelease`

[view_assembly_location_in_Android_Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Rgu.png)

(Note: some steps in android studio pause multiple times, so make sure to wait for several minutes before going to next step to make sure the step was completely executed)

Then, after completing the steps, to locate the output file, go through this thread : [get_output](https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android/issues/1). Or, simply go to `tesseract4android\build\outputs\aar` directory.
Here, we get an .aar file.

Now, to get the libtesseract.so file, we first need to unzip the aar file ([how_to_unzip_aar_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241411/extract-code-from-aar-file-android)), and then open `jni` folder to get libtesseract.so and other .so files.

Note :
For detailed info about this issue, refer to [this](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/issues/196) thread.

### Additional info

For compiling Tesseract 4 for iOS platform, refer [here](https://github.com/chaoskyme/Tesseract-OCR-iOS)